# How to define a function in a for loop with an incremental variable in R?

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function that calculates the total stress, `σ_T`, using the incremental function below.

[image: Equation]

`x` is the input data from a text file. `τ` and `K` are unknown values and `dt` is a known constant.

The equation uses the output at each step, `σ_T`, in the equation for the next step. I previously defined this function in MATLAB using a `for` loop, but I have read this is not advised for R. I looked into apply, but I am not sure how to implement it with my incremental function.

The ultimate goal is to use this function in nonlinear regression analysis.

I have included sample data below my question. It includes a column titled `yT`, which is the output for `σ_T` when `K=773` and `τ=4.576`.

Added:

I tried using a for loop to define the equation, but I don't think it is correct. When I pass it to the regression analysis I get an error. I also changed the equation slightly from the original image.

```
yT <- function(x, tau, k){ 
for(i in seq(from=1, to=200, by=1)){
  if (i == 1) {    
    yO = 0 
    dx = 0
  } else {
    yO = yT       
    dx = x[i] - x[i-1] }

  yT = exp(-0.02/tau)*yO + ((k/2) * (1 + exp(-0.02/tau)*dx))
} }
```

```
time    x           yT
0.00    0.000E+00   0.00000
0.02    0.000E+00   0.00000
0.04    1.000E-05   0.00771
0.06    1.420E-05   0.01863
0.08    -1.800E-06  0.01716
0.10    3.000E-06   0.01940
0.12    2.080E-05   0.03536
0.14    2.410E-05   0.05379
0.16    8.000E-06   0.05973
0.18    -5.100E-06  0.05554
0.20    7.300E-06   0.06093
0.22    2.750E-05   0.08187
0.24    2.560E-05   0.10126
0.26    6.800E-06   0.10606
0.28    -1.100E-06  0.10475
0.30    1.350E-05   0.11471
0.32    2.670E-05   0.13480
0.34    1.520E-05   0.14594
0.36    -6.000E-06  0.14067
0.38    -5.700E-06  0.13566
0.40    1.200E-05   0.14433
0.42    1.570E-05   0.15581
0.44    3.400E-06   0.15775
0.46    -3.800E-06  0.15413
0.48    7.300E-06   0.15909
0.50    1.970E-05   0.17359
0.52    1.530E-05   0.18464
0.54    7.000E-07   0.18437
0.56    -3.200E-06  0.18110
0.58    1.200E-05   0.18956
0.60    2.220E-05   0.20586
0.62    1.480E-05   0.21638
0.64    2.600E-06   0.21744
0.66    3.900E-06   0.21950
0.68    1.740E-05   0.23196
0.70    2.180E-05   0.24777
0.72    8.800E-06   0.25347
0.74    -4.200E-06  0.24913
0.76    5.600E-06   0.25236
0.78    2.200E-05   0.26823
0.80    2.000E-05   0.28249
0.82    6.000E-06   0.28588
0.84    7.000E-06   0.29004
0.86    1.700E-05   0.30188
0.88    1.800E-05   0.31445
0.90    2.000E-06   0.31462
0.92    -2.000E-06  0.31171
0.94    1.400E-05   0.32115
0.96    2.200E-05   0.33671
0.98    1.200E-05   0.34450
1.00    6.000E-06   0.34763
1.02    1.500E-05   0.35768
1.04    2.200E-05   0.37309
1.06    1.200E-05   0.38072
1.08    0.000E+00   0.37906
1.10    8.000E-06   0.38358
1.12    2.100E-05   0.39810
1.14    1.900E-05   0.41102
1.16    8.000E-06   0.41540
1.18    1.000E-05   0.42130
1.20    2.200E-05   0.43643
1.22    2.000E-05   0.44995
1.24    4.000E-06   0.45108
1.26    1.000E-06   0.44988
1.28    1.800E-05   0.46180
1.30    2.300E-05   0.47753
1.32    1.200E-05   0.48470
1.34    8.000E-06   0.48876
1.36    1.800E-05   0.50051
1.38    2.400E-05   0.51684
1.40    1.200E-05   0.52384
1.42    0.000E+00   0.52156
1.44    1.100E-05   0.52777
1.46    2.600E-05   0.54552
1.48    1.900E-05   0.55780
1.50    8.000E-06   0.56154
1.52    1.300E-05   0.56911
1.54    2.600E-05   0.58669
1.56    2.100E-05   0.60033
1.58    3.000E-06   0.60002
1.60    4.000E-06   0.60049
1.62    2.200E-05   0.61484
1.64    2.500E-05   0.63144
1.66    1.400E-05   0.63949
1.68    9.000E-06   0.64364
1.70    2.200E-05   0.65780
1.72    2.500E-05   0.67422
1.74    1.100E-05   0.67976
1.76    2.000E-06   0.67834
1.78    1.400E-05   0.68618
1.80    2.800E-05   0.70478
1.82    1.900E-05   0.71637
1.84    9.000E-06   0.72018
1.86    1.600E-05   0.72938
1.88    2.800E-05   0.74780
1.90    2.100E-05   0.76074
1.92    3.000E-06   0.75973
1.94    6.000E-06   0.76105
1.96    2.500E-05   0.77701
1.98    2.600E-05   0.79368
2.00    1.300E-05   0.80024
2.02    1.200E-05   0.80601
2.04    2.600E-05   0.82255
2.06    2.800E-05   0.84056
2.08    1.100E-05   0.84538
2.10    2.000E-06   0.84323
2.12    1.800E-05   0.85344
2.14    3.000E-05   0.87286
2.16    2.000E-05   0.88448
2.18    1.000E-05   0.88833
2.20    2.100E-05   0.90066
2.22    3.100E-05   0.92064
2.24    2.000E-05   0.93205
2.26    3.000E-06   0.93030
2.28    1.000E-05   0.93396
2.30    2.700E-05   0.95071
2.32    2.500E-05   0.96585
2.34    1.200E-05   0.97089
2.36    1.500E-05   0.97823
2.38    2.900E-05   0.99633
2.40    2.700E-05   1.01281
2.42    1.000E-05   1.01611
2.44    5.000E-06   1.01553
2.46    2.000E-05   1.02653
2.48    2.900E-05   1.04442
2.50    2.000E-05   1.05529
2.52    1.200E-05   1.05995
2.54    2.400E-05   1.07384
2.56    3.200E-05   1.09384
2.58    1.800E-05   1.10295
2.60    4.000E-06   1.10122
2.62    1.300E-05   1.10645
2.64    2.900E-05   1.12399
2.66    2.400E-05   1.13760
2.68    1.400E-05   1.14344
2.70    1.700E-05   1.15157
2.72    3.000E-05   1.16968
2.74    2.600E-05   1.18464
2.76    7.000E-06   1.18487
2.78    7.000E-06   1.18510
2.80    2.400E-05   1.19845
2.82    2.900E-05   1.21559
2.84    1.700E-05   1.22340
2.86    1.300E-05   1.22809
2.88    2.500E-05   1.24202
2.90    3.200E-05   1.26128
2.92    1.600E-05   1.26812
2.94    5.000E-06   1.26645
2.96    1.600E-05   1.27327
2.98    2.800E-05   1.28931
3.00    2.100E-05   1.29989
3.02    1.500E-05   1.30579
3.04    2.000E-05   1.31552
3.06    2.800E-05   1.33138
3.08    2.200E-05   1.34254
3.10    9.000E-06   1.34363
3.12    1.100E-05   1.34626
3.14    2.400E-05   1.35890
3.16    2.600E-05   1.37303
3.18    1.600E-05   1.37938
3.20    1.400E-05   1.38416
3.22    2.700E-05   1.39895
3.24    2.700E-05   1.41368
3.26    1.200E-05   1.41677
3.28    4.000E-06   1.41367
3.30    1.900E-05   1.42217
3.32    2.900E-05   1.43833
3.34    2.100E-05   1.44826
3.36    1.600E-05   1.45428
3.38    2.200E-05   1.46491
3.40    3.000E-05   1.48166
3.42    1.900E-05   1.48985
3.44    6.000E-06   1.48798
3.46    1.300E-05   1.49152
3.48    2.600E-05   1.50507
3.50    2.400E-05   1.51702
3.52    1.600E-05   1.52275
3.54    1.900E-05   1.53076
3.56    2.900E-05   1.54645
3.58    2.400E-05   1.55822
3.60    1.400E-05   1.56222
3.62    1.800E-05   1.56930
3.64    2.600E-05   1.58251
3.66    1.700E-05   1.58872
3.68    9.000E-06   1.58873
3.70    2.100E-05   1.59800
3.72    2.800E-05   1.61263
3.74    1.700E-05   1.61871
3.76    1.400E-05   1.62245
3.78    2.500E-05   1.63466
3.80    2.700E-05   1.64835
3.82    1.300E-05   1.65119
3.84    1.500E-05   1.65556
3.86    2.600E-05   1.66840
3.88    2.300E-05   1.67886
3.90    1.100E-05   1.68002
3.92    1.700E-05   1.68581
3.94    2.800E-05   1.70005
3.96    2.100E-05   1.70884
3.98    1.100E-05   1.70987
4.00    2.100E-05   1.71861
4.02    2.700E-05   1.73194
4.04    1.700E-05   1.73750
4.06    1.200E-05   1.73918
4.08    2.400E-05   1.75011
4.10    2.700E-05   1.76330
4.12    1.400E-05   1.76641
4.14    1.400E-05   1.76951
4.16    2.700E-05   1.78262
4.18    2.400E-05   1.79335
4.20    1.100E-05   1.79402
4.22    1.900E-05   1.80085
4.24    2.900E-05   1.81536
4.26    2.000E-05   1.82287
4.28    1.100E-05   1.82341
4.30    2.200E-05   1.83243
4.32    2.800E-05   1.84603
4.34    1.700E-05   1.85109
4.36    1.300E-05   1.85305
4.38    2.500E-05   1.86425
4.40    2.700E-05   1.87695
4.42    1.500E-05   1.88033
4.44    1.400E-05   1.88293
4.46    2.600E-05   1.89477
4.48    2.300E-05   1.90425
4.50    1.300E-05   1.90597
4.52    1.800E-05   1.91155
4.54    2.900E-05   1.92558
4.56    2.000E-05   1.93261
4.58    1.200E-05   1.93343
4.60    2.100E-05   1.94120
4.62    2.800E-05   1.95433
4.64    1.700E-05   1.95892
4.66    1.300E-05   1.96041
4.68    2.400E-05   1.97037
4.70    2.700E-05   1.98260
4.72    1.500E-05   1.98553
4.74    1.500E-05   1.98844
4.76    2.700E-05   2.00059
4.78    2.400E-05   2.01038
4.80    1.200E-05   2.01087
4.82    1.800E-05   2.01598
4.84    2.900E-05   2.02956
4.86    2.000E-05   2.03613
4.88    1.200E-05   2.03651
4.90    2.100E-05   2.04383
4.92    2.800E-05   2.05651
4.94    1.700E-05   2.06066
4.96    1.300E-05   2.06170
4.98    2.600E-05   2.07276
5.00    2.500E-05   2.08300
5.02    1.400E-05   2.08472
5.04    1.600E-05   2.08797
5.06    2.800E-05   2.10046
5.08    2.400E-05   2.10981
5.10    1.200E-05   2.10987
5.12    1.900E-05   2.11532
5.14    2.800E-05   2.12769
5.16    2.100E-05   2.13461
5.18    1.300E-05   2.13533
5.20    2.200E-05   2.14299
5.22    2.900E-05   2.15601
5.24    1.800E-05   2.16049
5.26    1.400E-05   2.16187
5.28    2.400E-05   2.17095
5.30    2.700E-05   2.18231
5.32    1.500E-05   2.18437
5.34    1.400E-05   2.18564
5.36    2.700E-05   2.19693
5.38    2.500E-05   2.20663
5.40    1.400E-05   2.20781
5.42    1.900E-05   2.21284
5.44    2.900E-05   2.22556
5.46    2.000E-05   2.23128
5.48    1.300E-05   2.23157
5.50    2.200E-05   2.23881
5.52    2.700E-05   2.24987
5.54    1.700E-05   2.25317
5.56    1.300E-05   2.25338
5.58    2.500E-05   2.26283
5.60    1.800E-05   2.26685
5.62    -1.200E-05  2.24771
5.64    -2.800E-05  2.21631
5.66    -4.000E-06  2.20356
5.68    2.000E-05   2.20937
5.70    1.100E-05   2.20822
5.72    -8.000E-06  2.19242
5.74    -1.200E-05  2.17361
5.76    -1.000E-06  2.16336
5.78    6.000E-06   2.15855
5.80    4.000E-06   2.15222
5.82    2.000E-06   2.14438
5.84    3.000E-06   2.13734
5.86    4.000E-06   2.13111
5.88    3.000E-06   2.12413
5.90    4.000E-06   2.11795
5.92    4.000E-06   2.11180
5.94    3.000E-06   2.10490
5.96    -3.000E-06  2.09341
5.98    -1.300E-05  2.07425
6.00    -1.200E-05  2.05595
6.02    0.000E+00   2.04699
6.04    5.000E-06   2.04192
6.06    3.000E-06   2.03533
6.08    3.000E-06   2.02877
6.10    3.000E-06   2.02223
6.12    2.000E-06   2.01496
6.14    2.000E-06   2.00771
6.16    4.000E-06   2.00204
6.18    4.000E-06   1.99640
6.20    3.000E-06   1.99000
6.22    2.000E-06   1.98287
6.24    -8.000E-06  1.96805
6.26    -1.500E-05  1.94790
6.28    -8.000E-06  1.93323
6.30    5.000E-06   1.92866
6.32    4.000E-06   1.92334
6.34    1.000E-06   1.91572
6.36    2.000E-06   1.90891
6.38    3.000E-06   1.90290
6.40    3.000E-06   1.89691
6.42    2.000E-06   1.89018
6.44    3.000E-06   1.88425
6.46    3.000E-06   1.87835
6.48    3.000E-06   1.87247
6.50    4.000E-06   1.86739
6.52    -1.000E-06  1.85848
6.54    -1.200E-05  1.84112
6.56    -1.300E-05  1.82306
6.58    -2.000E-06  1.81357
6.60    5.000E-06   1.80952
6.62    2.000E-06   1.80317
6.64    1.000E-06   1.79608
6.66    3.000E-06   1.79056
6.68    2.000E-06   1.78429
6.70    2.000E-06   1.77806
6.72    1.000E-06   1.77107
6.74    2.000E-06   1.76489
6.76    4.000E-06   1.76028
6.78    3.000E-06   1.75492
6.80    3.000E-06   1.74958
6.82    2.000E-06   1.74349
6.84    -5.000E-06  1.73203
6.86    -1.400E-05  1.71368
6.88    -1.000E-05  1.69850
6.90    3.000E-06   1.69340
6.92    5.000E-06   1.68987
6.94    1.000E-06   1.68328
6.96    1.000E-06   1.67671
6.98    1.000E-06   1.67017
7.00    2.000E-06   1.66443
7.02    4.000E-06   1.66025
7.04    3.000E-06   1.65533
7.06    2.000E-06   1.64965
7.08    2.000E-06   1.64400
7.10    2.000E-06   1.63837
7.12    2.000E-06   1.63277
7.14    2.000E-06   1.62719
7.16    0.000E+00   1.62010
7.18    -9.000E-06  1.60609
7.20    -1.400E-05  1.58829
7.22    -5.000E-06  1.57751
7.24    5.000E-06   1.57448
7.26    3.000E-06   1.56993
7.28    0.000E+00   1.56308
7.30    2.000E-06   1.55781
7.32    1.000E-06   1.55179
7.34    2.000E-06   1.54656
7.36    2.000E-06   1.54136
7.38    2.000E-06   1.53618
7.40    2.000E-06   1.53103
7.42    2.000E-06   1.52589
7.44    2.000E-06   1.52078
7.46    2.000E-06   1.51569
7.48    2.000E-06   1.51062
7.50    1.000E-06   1.50481
7.52    2.000E-06   1.49979
7.54    -3.000E-06  1.49093
7.56    -1.200E-05  1.47518
7.58    -1.200E-05  1.45949
7.60    1.000E-06   1.45390
7.62    4.000E-06   1.45064
7.64    1.000E-06   1.44509
7.66    1.000E-06   1.43955
7.68    1.000E-06   1.43405
7.70    1.000E-06   1.42857
7.72    1.000E-06   1.42311
7.74    2.000E-06   1.41844
7.76    3.000E-06   1.41457
7.78    3.000E-06   1.41072
7.80    1.000E-06   1.40534
7.82    1.000E-06   1.39998
7.84    2.000E-06   1.39542
7.86    1.000E-06   1.39010
7.88    3.000E-06   1.38636
7.90    2.000E-06   1.38185
7.92    1.000E-06   1.37660
7.94    0.000E+00   1.37059
7.96    -7.000E-06  1.35922
7.98    -1.400E-05  1.34249
8.00    -8.000E-06  1.33047
8.02    3.000E-06   1.32698
8.04    3.000E-06   1.32351
8.06    1.000E-06   1.31851
8.08    1.000E-06   1.31353
8.10    1.000E-06   1.30857
8.12    1.000E-06   1.30364
8.14    2.000E-06   1.29949
8.16    1.000E-06   1.29460
8.18    1.000E-06   1.28972
8.20    2.000E-06   1.28564
8.22    1.000E-06   1.28081
8.24    2.000E-06   1.27676
8.26    1.000E-06   1.27197
8.28    2.000E-06   1.26796
8.30    1.000E-06   1.26321
8.32    1.000E-06   1.25847
8.34    2.000E-06   1.25452
8.36    0.000E+00   1.24905
8.38    2.000E-06   1.24515
8.40    2.000E-06   1.24126
8.42    0.000E+00   1.23585
8.44    -7.000E-06  1.22506
8.46    -1.600E-05  1.20738
8.48    -5.000E-06  1.19825
8.50    4.000E-06   1.19611
8.52    3.000E-06   1.19321
8.54    -1.000E-06  1.18724
8.56    1.000E-06   1.18283
8.58    1.000E-06   1.17844
8.60    1.000E-06   1.17408
8.62    1.000E-06   1.16973
8.64    1.000E-06   1.16540
8.66    2.000E-06   1.16186
8.68    1.000E-06   1.15756
8.70    1.000E-06   1.15329
8.72    0.000E+00   1.14826
8.74    1.000E-06   1.14402
8.76    1.000E-06   1.13980
8.78    2.000E-06   1.13638
8.80    1.000E-06   1.13219
8.82    1.000E-06   1.12803
8.84    1.000E-06   1.12388
8.86    1.000E-06   1.11975
8.88    2.000E-06   1.11641
8.90    1.000E-06   1.11231
8.92    1.000E-06   1.10823
8.94    1.000E-06   1.10417
8.96    1.000E-06   1.10013
8.98    1.000E-06   1.09610
9.00    -5.000E-06  1.08746
9.02    -1.400E-05  1.07192
9.04    -1.000E-05  1.05954
9.06    2.000E-06   1.05646
9.08    4.000E-06   1.05494
9.10    0.000E+00   1.05034
9.12    0.000E+00   1.04575
9.14    1.000E-06   1.04197
9.16    0.000E+00   1.03742
9.18    1.000E-06   1.03367
9.20    1.000E-06   1.02993
9.22    0.000E+00   1.02544
9.24    1.000E-06   1.02174
9.26    1.000E-06   1.01806
9.28    1.000E-06   1.01439
9.30    1.000E-06   1.01074
9.32    2.000E-06   1.00787
9.34    0.000E+00   1.00348
9.36    1.000E-06   0.99987
9.38    2.000E-06   0.99705
9.40    2.000E-06   0.99425
9.42    1.000E-06   0.99068
9.44    1.000E-06   0.98714
9.46    1.000E-06   0.98360
9.48    0.000E+00   0.97931
9.50    0.000E+00   0.97504
9.52    1.000E-06   0.97156
9.54    1.000E-06   0.96810
9.56    0.000E+00   0.96387
9.58    1.000E-06   0.96044
9.60    1.000E-06   0.95702
9.62    1.000E-06   0.95362
9.64    1.000E-06   0.95024
9.66    1.000E-06   0.94686
9.68    1.000E-06   0.94350
9.70    1.000E-06   0.94016
9.72    -4.000E-06  0.93298
9.74    -1.300E-05  0.91888
9.76    -1.100E-05  0.90639
9.78    0.000E+00   0.90244
9.80    3.000E-06   0.90082
9.82    0.000E+00   0.89689
9.84    0.000E+00   0.89298
9.86    0.000E+00   0.88908
9.88    0.000E+00   0.88520
9.90    1.000E-06   0.88212
9.92    1.000E-06   0.87904
9.94    0.000E+00   0.87521
9.96    0.000E+00   0.87139
9.98    2.000E-06   0.86913
10.00   0.000E+00   0.86534
```

Comment: look into dput for passing data forward, also consider posting the answer to facilitate, and finally try to display what you have coded so far, good luck and welcome to so

Comment: The "advice" that for loops should be avoided in R isn't really the best advice. There are plenty of cases where they are justified, just they aren't as necessary as they are in other languages because many operation are vectoried. However in the case where you are using output as input inside of a loop, they are just what you need. (Though you could possibly consider a Reduce operation as well). Be sure to share your function rather than having us translate math into code for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. That makes sense about for loops for this case. I added my attempt at writing a for loop to define the function, but it is not working for the regression analysis so I am guessing I defined it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Not using your formula but just showing how you can calculate a new variable (column) based on previous values by using the `lag` function. In this simple case I calculate `value` to be the sum of `x` the current time stamp and `yT` of the previous time stamp. Off course, the first value will be `NA` as there is no value of `yT` before the time = 0.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

set.seed(123)
data <- tibble(
  time = seq(0, 5, by = 0.02),
  x = runif(-10, 10, n = 251),
  yT = runif(0, 2, n = 251)
)

data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(value = x + lag(yT, 1))
```

In base-R the solution is as simple:

```
data$value  <-  data$x + lag(data$yT)
```

There is no need for an explicit for loop as many R functions are vectorized: at the C-level the function loops through the vector elements. C-code is usually faster than R code.

My recommendation is if you can vectorize: do it. Apply and map functions can result in faster code than a for loop but you really need to understand the effects of immutable objects in R to do a proper assessement. 
My opinion is that apply & map functions are more elegant and allow for better readable code and safer looping (you need to worry about indexing and exit conditions). When your current loop relies on a result from a previous loop I think explicit for loops are required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your example but I am not sure how to use this to create a function to pass to the nls function for regression analysis. Would I need to create function for yT afterward?

Answer (score 0):

How about recursion?

```
sigma.T <- function(x,tao,kay,dt,n) {
  yT = exp(-dt/tao) + ((kay/2) * (1 + exp(-dt/tao)*x))
  if (n == 1)    return (yT)
  else           return (sigma.T(x=x,tao=tao,kay=kay,dt=dt,n=n-1) * yT)
}

sigma.T(x=0,tao=4.576,kay=773,dt=0.01,n=10)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but I was not able to pass it to the nls function for regression analysis. Is there something else I would need to do before that?